# how can I wrap the tag group-wise?

Tags: jquery

I may have any number of articles in my html:

```
<div id="main">
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</div>
```

Now, I wanted to split in a group of all articles.

```
var group = parseInt($('#main article').length / 3, 10); // results 4
```

Now, how can I wrap it with four articles in a group?

The result should be this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="group">
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
  </div>
  <div class="group"><!--the remaining two articles-->
     <article></article>
     <article></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it should be `length` not `lenght`

Comment: What output you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a simple for loop

```
var $articles = $('#main article'),
    length = $articles.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i = i + 4) {
    $articles.slice(i, i + 4).wrapAll('<div class="group"/>')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PQN3v/)

Comment: any idea if I wanted to wrap last two articles sharing in first and second group?

Comment: if it was exactly 12/3 = 4 then it's okay but if it's 14/3= 4 then remaining 2 should be adjusted to first and second and third group correspondingly taking one bye one.

Comment: @C-link so you want to have only 3 groups is that it

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
while($('#main > article').length > 0)
{
    $('#main > article:lt(4)').wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fAE5g/)

Answer (score 0):

```
        var group = parseInt($('#main article').length / 3, 10); // results 4
        var grpCount = Math.ceil($('#main article').length / group);

        for(var i=0 ; i < grpCount ;i++){
            if(i == 0) {
                $('#main article:lt('+group+')').wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>")
            } else if( i == (grpCount-1)) {
                $('#main article:gt('+parseInt((group*i)-1)+')').wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>")
            } else {
                $('#main article:lt('+parseInt(group*(i+1))+'):gt('+parseInt((group*i)-1)+')').wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>")
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try `.each()` jquery function:

```
var articles = $('#main').find('article');

$.each(articles, function(i, el) {
  if(i % 4 == 0) {
    articles.slice(i , i+4).wrapAll('<div class="group">');
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LsGzi)